# can't import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException;

Tags: java, spring, web, backend

I haven not being able to import the following library to use it for handling some error. I have been looking up on internet about this problem but cannot succeed. Is it that i have to download an specific .jar? if so, I would appreciate the help to know how to do it. I am pretty new into this web and spring stuff.

Code:

```
package org.magnum.dataup;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.magnum.dataup.model.Video;
import org.magnum.dataup.model.VideoStatus;
import org.magnum.dataup.model.VideoStatus.VideoState;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException;

@Controller
public class VideoController {

  public static final String VIDEO_SVC_PATH = "/video";
  public static final String VIDEO_DATA_PATH = VIDEO_SVC_PATH + "/{id}/data";
  private static final AtomicLong currentId = new AtomicLong(0L);

  private Map<Long, Video> videos = new HashMap<Long, Video>();

  @RequestMapping(value = VIDEO_SVC_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody Collection<Video> getVideoList() {
    return videos.values();
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = VIDEO_DATA_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void getData(@PathVariable("id") long id, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException {
    VideoFileManager videoData = VideoFileManager.get();

    try {
      videoData.copyVideoData(videos.get(id), response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = VIDEO_SVC_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody Video addVideoMetadata(@RequestBody Video v, HttpServletRequest request)
      throws IOException {
    v.setId(currentId.incrementAndGet());
    v.setDataUrl(getUrlBaseForLocalServer(request) + "/" + VIDEO_SVC_PATH + v.getId() + "/data");
    videos.put(v.getId(), v);
    return v;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = VIDEO_DATA_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody VideoStatus addVideoData(@PathVariable("id") long id,
      @RequestParam MultipartFile data) throws IOException {
    VideoFileManager videoData = VideoFileManager.get();
    try {
      videoData.saveVideoData(videos.get(id), data.getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
    return new VideoStatus(VideoState.READY);
  }

  private String getUrlBaseForLocalServer(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String baseURL = "http://" + request.getServerName()
        + ((request.getServerPort() != 80) ? ":" + request.getServerPort() : "");
    return baseURL;
  }

}
```

Error Message when importing:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share the procedure to add the dependency in gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar you looking for is available from maven repo [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-webmvc) .

If you use maven for dependency management just add this to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>
```

Comment: hi cesar, i forgot to mention im using gradle

Comment: Import with 

`compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-rest-webmvc', version: '3.3.3.RELEASE'` 

You can check the import for your case in [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/3.3.3.RELEASE)

Comment: I added it right below implementation() and inside the dependencies body:

dependencies {
    implementation(":autograder.handin:1.0.0")
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-rest-webmvc', version: '3.3.3.RELEASE'
}

Is that correct?

Comment: I am not familiar with gradle, you can check gradle documentation

Comment: MAVEN TO GRADLE CONVERTOR : https://sagioto.github.io/maven2gradle/